# C++ issue separating array creation from function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm starting to use c++ after a while to do some directx programming and I'm having a seemingly dumb issue. 
I have a buffer that is currently using an array that is created inline:

```
Vertex vertices[]={{...},{...},...};
```

This array is used as a resource for the buffer creation. The issue I'm having is that I want to retrieve this array from a function because I want to create different structures that are not hard coded inside the method that creates the buffer. However, if I do something like Vertex* vertices=getDefaultVertices() where the definition for getDefaultVertices() is Vertex* getDefaultVertices() and return the structure I had above it will not work. Now I've found by looking around that part of the issue is that you can't create a local function array in c++ and return a reference to it. My question is what should I do to be able to retrieve this array? the only thing I can think of is to use a class with constants but I'd like to know a solution that uses a function to retrieve the array if possible.

Comment: Relieve yourself and use `std::vector`.

Comment: A vector surely is a good idea if you can use modern C++ (so that returning a vector is cheap because it's a move). If that's not the case you can allocate space dynamically so that its life time is decoupled from the scope, e.g. by using new().

Comment: typedef struct D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA {
  const void *pSysMem;
  UINT       SysMemPitch;
  UINT       SysMemSlicePitch;
} D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA;
this is what the subresource takes, in particular pSysMem would be the vertices

Comment: @PeterSchneider: No worries, NRVO is old-tech.

Comment: You can create a "local function array" and return a pointer or reference to it, no trouble. It just better had be `static` though, in which case you might run into reentrancy and multithreadig issues. Unless they are constant.

Comment: I went with the constants solution I mentioned for now, tried several variations and could not get it to work the way I wanted. I know I could possibly use a vector and then just create the array at runtime depending on what is on the vector but I haven't gotten there yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about:

```
vector<Vertex>& defaultVertices()
{
    static vector<Vertex> defVtx;
    if(defVtx.size() == 0)
    {
        // declare your vertices one after the other:
        defVtx.push_back(Vertex(0.1f,0.2f,0.3f));    // first Vertex
        defVtx.push_back(Vertex(0.1f,0.2f,0.3f));    // second Vertex
    }
    return defVtx;
}
```

That way you have a vector of vertices, that'll be always the same and it will be created once in memory.  I don't know how safe that is regarding multitasking (most likely there may be racing conditions when calling the very first time and a following call from different threads at the same time).

I know this is not a good solution, but it should fit your needs for now...

Comment: I guess in modern C++ you could initialize it with an initializer list directly when declaring it. That would also be thread safe.